# Instal postgres sql in windows 10

Tags: python, postgresql

I try to install the latest version of postgres sql using the latest version and the recommended set up.

However when I open the pg adming I receive this error.

```
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../web/pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 347, in create_app
    if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
    return version.value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Any help on how to fix it?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176413/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-value-pgadmin4

Comment: @cwittah That does not seem to be the answer. I am also having this issue, but the source of the attribute error is not in the configuration subsystem, but in the version of SQLite installed!?! Maybe conflicting Python versions?

Comment: Did you find any solution for the issue ?

Answer (score 6):

After trying all the other suggestions without success, it finally worked for me now, with the way suggested here: [Get fatal error: server could not be contacted when running pgAdmin4. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527280/get-fatal-error-server-could-not-be-contacted-when-running-pgadmin4-nonetype)

1. Install the newest version of the standalone pgAdmin from https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/
   (you can do the installation additionally to the existing bundled version, without having to remove anything before)
2. Delete the C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin folder
3. (I restarted the postgres service once again)
4. Run the new pgAdmin as Administrator - it works!

Several people report that, from then on, even the old bundled version of pgAdmin works fine!

Comment: Realized just now that @ACaps described the exact same steps already a day before in this thread. Just because I was unable to run the StackBuilder as well as suggested there, I stopped following the further steps... That was a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved in this way:

- I removed PGadmin from "Application Stack Builder"
- download last version v4 5.2 (pgAdmin 4 v5.2 (released April 22, 2021)
- installed...
- lunched like admin... (error as usual)
- clean-up folder C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin (opsssss)
- lunched like admin... All ran successfully!

Using all in one PGadmin with Application Stack gave me an usual error bind to some pyton or configuration file

Alen

Answer (score 3):

I had a lot of trouble launching pgAdmin. Several solutions are there.

1. Try an older version of pgAdmin. The latest version might have unresolved issues.
2. Go to %APPDATA% (C:\Users{{your username}}\AppData\Roaming) folder and delete the pgadmin folder and run again.
3. go to environment variables (search environment on search bar) -> advanced, the click on Environment Variables. On System Variables click on path and set a new path for C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin (the address might vary on your PC)

Comment: the env variable did the trick for me. Thank you